# Semi-norms generating the usual topology of Schwartz space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, locally-convex-spaces, schwartz-space

Consider the following family of semi-norms on the Schwartz space

$$\|f\|_{m,n}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|(1+|x|)^m f^{(n)}(x)|  \;\;\; m,n\in \{0,1,2,...\} $$

It is well known in the litterature that the family above induce the same locally convex topology on the Schwartz space as the family

$$\|f\|_{m,n}=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|x^m f^{(n)}(x)|  \;\;\; m,n\in \{0,1,2,...\} $$

I can not figure out what is the advantages/interests of using the first family of semi-norms instead of the second.
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The sequence of weights $(1+|x|)^m$ is increasing.

Comment: thank you so much.